The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[room.schemaLocation, kapt.kotlin.generated]'
I am trying to add Room, kapt, and hilt in my android app but I am not getting into anything, I know you will ask why using kapt instead of ksp, before adding the code of the database and so on ksp alone didn't let me run my app successfully until I changed to kapt .
Now when building the gradle everything is okay, but when Running the App I get this error :
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:319)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:108)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:320)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:266)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
    ... 34 more


BUILD FAILED in 9s
28 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 24 up-to-date




My build.gradle is :
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.dadixcod.mytodo"
    compileSdk = 34



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.dadixcod.mytodo"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += mapOf(
                    "room.schemaLocation" to "$projectDir/schemas".toString()
                )
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.15"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")


    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

Here is My Database code :
package com.dadixcod.mytodo.data

import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase


@Database(
    entities = [Todo::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class TodoDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao:TodoDao
}

I tried upgrading to ksp , I tried to add room {schemaDirectory ...} and nothing worked

Bro, I am using room with ksp and it works well.

Have you added a room plugin at the build.gradle Project level and module level?
id("androidx.room") version "$room_version" apply false and id("androidx.room")

It is recommended by Google to use ksp instead of kapt. Please try to set ksp with Room up as follows:
In your top-level build.gradle file, make sure to declare the ksp plugin:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.0' apply false
    //...
    // choose a KSP version that matches your Kotlin version
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.9.0-1.0.13' apply false
}

Then, in your module-level build.gradle file, add the following plugins and dependencies:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    //...
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
}

dependencies {
    //...
    def room_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}

Finally, sync your project with the Gradle files.
Please report back if that works in your case.

It worked but I have another problem I think it is with hilt , can you sir leave me any contact so I can reach if you can help me solve this problem ?
Or should I add another post here

I'm happy to hear it worked! Please open a new question here on stackoverflow.
